# Scrollable PHP 'generated' Table With Fixed Header

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to display a table (scrollable) with a fixed header. And it doesn't seem to work. I scoured the Internet for solutions and none of them work... All of the examples on the Internet are using tables with data inserted manually in the HTML code. But here, I'm calling data from a database using PHP.

**PHP/HTML**

```
<?php
include ('sambungan.php');
?>

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "senarai.css">

<h2>SENARAI NAMA PELAJAR</h2>
<div class = 'senarai'>
<table>
    <tr class = 'header'>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>No Kad Pengenalan</th>
        <th>Nama</th>
        <th>Katalaluan</th>
        <th>E-mel</th>
    </tr>
    <div class = 'tbl_content'>
        <?php
        $sql = 'select murid.id_murid , murid.no_kp_murid , nama_murid.nama_murid , murid.katalaluan , nama_murid.email_murid FROM murid INNER JOIN nama_murid ON nama_murid.id_nama = murid.id_nama';
        $result = mysqli_query($sambungan,$sql);
        while($pelajar = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
                echo '<tr class = "data">
                <td>'.$pelajar["id_murid"].'</td> 
                <td>'.$pelajar["no_kp_murid"].'</td>
                <td>'.$pelajar["nama_murid"].'</td>
                <td>'.$pelajar["katalaluan"].'</td>
                <td>'.$pelajar["email_murid"].'</td>
                </tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
table
{
    font-family: 'Cutive Mono' , monospace;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    
    width: 1600px;
    max-height: 500px;
    border-spacing: 0 1rem;
}

div.senarai
{
  height: 530px;
  width: 1600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 15px var(--shadowDark), -8px -8px 15px var(--shadowLight);
}

.header
{
    position: sticky;
    background-color: #405D4F;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    z-index: 1;
}

th
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    height: 70px !important;
    background-color: #405D4F;
}

td,th
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 8px;
}

div.tbl_content
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I noticed that the PHP code doesn't seem to be placed inside the 'tbl_content' div. Because when I adjust the height of the div, the table goes down and there's white space above as if the div was above the table? WHY?

Comment: Try giving your div.tbl_content a fixed height of, say 400px, and overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y : auto, if it works, adjust the height the way you want it to be.

Comment: Don't use `table > div`. But you can use `div` inside `th` and `td`

Comment: @NicholasMberev it still doesn't work. Like I said...the div 'pushes' the table down when actually the table should be inside the div right? This is sooo confusing. I'm getting crazy over this

Comment: @user3733831 I'm sorry I don't really understand what you exactly mean. But I tried putting the ```div.tbl_content``` inside the php function. meaning, the div is echoed by the php function. Still didn't work. Same thing happened it's as if the div is above the table?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **jQuery DataTable**? It has more features like `Paging`, `Sorting`, `Searching`, etc even `Fixed header` as well. More over, its very easy to implement and use.

Official example docs: https://datatables.net/examples/index

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "scrollY":        "200px",
  "scrollCollapse": true,
  "paging":         false
} );
```

The above code is to implement Scrollable Table with Fixed Header using jQuery DataTable.

Comment: I would love to try jQuery as it is powerful. But unfortunately I have no prior experiences in jQuery..and this is for my final year school project. So yeah, don't really want to take a gamble. nevertheless, jQuery would be a last resort. If all things don't work

Answer (score 0):

You can’t position: `sticky;` a `<thead>`. Nor a `<tr>`. But you can sticky a `<th>`, which means you can make sticky headers inside a regular ol’ `<table>`. Look at this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/).

Just you start with:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
th, td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
tr.red th {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="red">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Job</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Qui!</td>
      <td>Accusamus?</td>
      <td>Minima?</td>
      <td>Dolorum.</td>
      <td>Molestiae.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vero!</td>
      <td>Voluptatum?</td>
      <td>Ea?</td>
      <td>Odit!</td>
      <td>A.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Debitis.</td>
      <td>Veniam.</td>
      <td>Fuga.</td>
      <td>Alias!</td>
      <td>Recusandae!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aperiam!</td>
      <td>Dolorum.</td>
      <td>Enim.</td>
      <td>Sapiente!</td>
      <td>Suscipit?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Consequuntur.</td>
      <td>Doloremque.</td>
      <td>Illum!</td>
      <td>Iste!</td>
      <td>Sint!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Facilis.</td>
      <td>Error.</td>
      <td>Fugiat.</td>
      <td>At.</td>
      <td>Modi?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptatibus!</td>
      <td>Alias.</td>
      <td>Eaque.</td>
      <td>Cum.</td>
      <td>Ducimus!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
      <td>Enim.</td>
      <td>Earum?</td>
      <td>Nobis?</td>
      <td>Eveniet.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eum!</td>
      <td>Id?</td>
      <td>Molestiae.</td>
      <td>Velit.</td>
      <td>Minima.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sapiente?</td>
      <td>Neque.</td>
      <td>Obcaecati!</td>
      <td>Earum.</td>
      <td>Esse.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nam?</td>
      <td>Ipsam!</td>
      <td>Provident.</td>
      <td>Ullam.</td>
      <td>Quae?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Amet!</td>
      <td>In.</td>
      <td>Officia!</td>
      <td>Natus?</td>
      <td>Tempore?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Consequatur.</td>
      <td>Hic.</td>
      <td>Officia.</td>
      <td>Itaque?</td>
      <td>Quasi.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enim.</td>
      <td>Tenetur.</td>
      <td>Asperiores?</td>
      <td>Eos!</td>
      <td>Libero.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Exercitationem.</td>
      <td>Quidem!</td>
      <td>Beatae?</td>
      <td>Adipisci?</td>
      <td>Accusamus.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Omnis.</td>
      <td>Accusamus?</td>
      <td>Eius!</td>
      <td>Recusandae!</td>
      <td>Dolor.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magni.</td>
      <td>Temporibus!</td>
      <td>Odio!</td>
      <td>Odit!</td>
      <td>Voluptatum?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eum.</td>
      <td>Animi!</td>
      <td>Labore.</td>
      <td>Alias!</td>
      <td>Fuga.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quia!</td>
      <td>Quis.</td>
      <td>Neque?</td>
      <td>Illo.</td>
      <td>Ad.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Officiis.</td>
      <td>Exercitationem!</td>
      <td>Adipisci?</td>
      <td>Officiis?</td>
      <td>In?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptates?</td>
      <td>Voluptatum.</td>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
      <td>Totam?</td>
      <td>Quisquam!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Soluta.</td>
      <td>Tempore!</td>
      <td>Cupiditate.</td>
      <td>Beatae.</td>
      <td>Perspiciatis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Porro.</td>
      <td>Officia?</td>
      <td>Error.</td>
      <td>Culpa?</td>
      <td>Fugit.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Et?</td>
      <td>Nemo.</td>
      <td>Nisi?</td>
      <td>Totam!</td>
      <td>Voluptate.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Saepe?</td>
      <td>Vero.</td>
      <td>Amet?</td>
      <td>Illo!</td>
      <td>Laborum!</td>
    </tr>
   
    <tr>
      <td>Blanditiis?</td>
      <td>Impedit.</td>
      <td>Libero?</td>
      <td>Reiciendis!</td>
      <td>Tempore.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quasi.</td>
      <td>Reiciendis.</td>
      <td>Aut?</td>
      <td>Architecto?</td>
      <td>Vero!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fuga!</td>
      <td>Illum!</td>
      <td>Tenetur!</td>
      <td>Vitae.</td>
      <td>Natus.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dolorem?</td>
      <td>Eaque!</td>
      <td>Vero?</td>
      <td>Quibusdam.</td>
      <td>Deleniti?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Minus.</td>
      <td>Accusantium?</td>
      <td>Ab.</td>
      <td>Cupiditate.</td>
      <td>Atque?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hic.</td>
      <td>Eligendi.</td>
      <td>Sit?</td>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
      <td>Dolor.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quidem.</td>
      <td>In?</td>
      <td>Nesciunt?</td>
      <td>Adipisci.</td>
      <td>Neque.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eos.</td>
      <td>Incidunt!</td>
      <td>Quis?</td>
      <td>Quod?</td>
      <td>Vitae!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ullam!</td>
      <td>Facilis.</td>
      <td>Tempora!</td>
      <td>Accusantium.</td>
      <td>Consequuntur?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Numquam?</td>
      <td>At.</td>
      <td>Incidunt.</td>
      <td>Tenetur?</td>
      <td>Voluptatem.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Iusto?</td>
      <td>Inventore.</td>
      <td>Molestias.</td>
      <td>Accusantium.</td>
      <td>Sunt.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Repellendus!</td>
      <td>Ex.</td>
      <td>Magnam.</td>
      <td>Odit!</td>
      <td>Iste?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id!</td>
      <td>Reiciendis?</td>
      <td>Rem.</td>
      <td>Quae!</td>
      <td>Laborum?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Exercitationem?</td>
      <td>Maiores.</td>
      <td>Minima.</td>
      <td>Nemo!</td>
      <td>Sequi.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Qui.</td>
      <td>Impedit?</td>
      <td>Reprehenderit.</td>
      <td>Distinctio.</td>
      <td>Natus?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suscipit!</td>
      <td>Tenetur.</td>
      <td>Cumque!</td>
      <td>Molestiae.</td>
      <td>Fugiat?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sunt?</td>
      <td>Quis?</td>
      <td>Officia.</td>
      <td>Incidunt.</td>
      <td>Voluptate.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Possimus.</td>
      <td>Mollitia!</td>
      <td>Eveniet!</td>
      <td>Temporibus.</td>
      <td>Mollitia!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Incidunt.</td>
      <td>Fugiat.</td>
      <td>Error.</td>
      <td>Odit.</td>
      <td>Cumque?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maxime?</td>
      <td>Qui!</td>
      <td>Sapiente!</td>
      <td>Natus.</td>
      <td>Soluta?</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

UPDATE: Example of a sticky table with `PHP` data. Same `CSS` from my above code snippet is used for this example also.

```
<?php
   $users =  [['id'=>1, 'name'=>'User Name 1', 'address'=>'User Address 1']
          ,['id'=>2, 'name'=>'User Name 2', 'address'=>'User Address 2']
          ,['id'=>3, 'name'=>'User Name 3', 'address'=>'User Address 3']
          ,['id'=>4, 'name'=>'User Name 4', 'address'=>'User Address 4']
          ,['id'=>5, 'name'=>'User Name 5', 'address'=>'User Address 5']
          ,['id'=>6, 'name'=>'User Name 6', 'address'=>'User Address 6']
          ,['id'=>7, 'name'=>'User Name 7', 'address'=>'User Address 7']
          ,['id'=>8, 'name'=>'User Name 8', 'address'=>'User Address 8']
          ,['id'=>9, 'name'=>'User Name 9', 'address'=>'User Address 9']
          ,['id'=>10, 'name'=>'User Name 10', 'address'=>'User Address 10']
          ,['id'=>11, 'name'=>'User Name 11', 'address'=>'User Address 11']
          ,['id'=>12, 'name'=>'User Name 12', 'address'=>'User Address 12']
          ,['id'=>13, 'name'=>'User Name 13', 'address'=>'User Address 13']
          ,['id'=>14, 'name'=>'User Name 14', 'address'=>'User Address 14']
          ,['id'=>15, 'name'=>'User Name 15', 'address'=>'User Address 15']
          ,['id'=>16, 'name'=>'User Name 16', 'address'=>'User Address 16']
          ,['id'=>17, 'name'=>'User Name 17', 'address'=>'User Address 17']
          ,['id'=>18, 'name'=>'User Name 18', 'address'=>'User Address 18']
          ,['id'=>19, 'name'=>'User Name 19', 'address'=>'User Address 19']
          ,['id'=>20, 'name'=>'User Name 20', 'address'=>'User Address 20']
          ];

$tdata ='';
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
  $id      = $value['id'];
  $name    = $value['name'];
  $address = $value['address'];

  $tdata .= "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td>$address</td><tr>\n";
}

?>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="red">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?=$tdata?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Output:

[image]

Another Example with your table data: If your query fetching result, this should work.

```
$sql = 'select m.id_murid
             , m.no_kp_murid 
             , n.nama_murid 
             , m.katalaluan 
             , n.email_murid 
        FROM murid AS m
          INNER JOIN nama_murid AS n ON n.id_nama = m.id_nama';
$result = mysqli_query($sambungan,$sql);
while($pelajar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $html .= '<tr class="data">
              <td>'.$pelajar["id_murid"].'</td> 
              <td>'.$pelajar["no_kp_murid"].'</td>
              <td>'.$pelajar["nama_murid"].'</td>
              <td>'.$pelajar["katalaluan"].'</td>
              <td>'.$pelajar["email_murid"].'</td>
            </tr>';
}

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class='header'>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>No Kad Pengenalan</th>
      <th>Nama</th>
      <th>Katalaluan</th>
      <th>E-mel</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?=$html?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. Useful knowledge but my problem here seems to be that the table can't even scroll down 

Comment: Are you sure you are getting data from your `SELECT` query?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Because the data shows up perfectly. It just doesn't scroll.

Comment: I don't know. I can't even test wether the header stcks, because the table won't even scroll